# unable to install k3b on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, k3b

I go to the software center, click install under k3b, and within seconds I am greeted with a message that says this:

```
CD/DVD 'Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120424.1)' is required

Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/media/cdrom/' to install software packages from it.
```

Comment: I get this error while installing K3b from software center installArchives() failed: Extracting templates from packages: 22%
Extracting templates from packages: 44%
Extracting templates from packages: 66%
Extracting templates from packages: 88%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ... Extracting templates from packages: 22%
Extracting templates from packages: 44%
Extracting templates from packages: 66%
Extracting templates from packages: 88%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ... Extracting templates from packages: 22%
Extracting templa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open software center.
- Goto  Edit > Software sources
- Uncheck Installable from CD ROM/ DVD
- Then run `sudo apt-get update`

  [image: softwareCenter]

Comment: Yes, your suggestion worked like a charm.